# Работа в Dev C++ с библиотекой graphics.h / windows.h

Tags: c, graphics, devc++

Я студент 1 курса. Дали задание на курсовой проект протабулировать формулу (зависимости мощности от времени) и построить график по результатам. Можно пользоваться Excel, но если сделаю график "вручную" (например, через указанные библиотеки примитивной графикой), то будет очень хорошо. 
Следовал руководству отсюда
[*Как писать простые графические программы?*](http://kpolyakov.spb.ru/school/c/faq.htm), но столкнулся с проблемой (скриншот прилагается). Посоветуйте, пожалуйста как её решить или другой путь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747110/c-graphics-h-lbgi-not-found), думаю, поможет.